# Split render script for VSE?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I am looking for an altenative of this script (which split renders a .blend file, much faster): https://github.com/jendabek/BlenderRenderController

but for Linux and working with the latest Blender version. Do you know how I can speed up VSE rendering? I think a bash script can help too (or a python), because there is this api: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html

But somebody must have written this already, I hope. I have 12 cores which I want to utilize.

Answer (score 1):

Use the parallel render add-on: https://github.com/elmopl/ktba/tree/master/scripts/addons

- Install it.
- Add an absolute path to ffmpeg in the add-on preferences.
- Find the Parallel Render options in the Render sidebar.

(For really fast render use AVI JPEG and PR, but you'll have to render audio separate afterwards and mux it yourself)

Comment: Thank you! The README is empty, how do I install it?

Comment: Download this file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elmopl/ktba/master/scripts/addons/parallel_render.py
(In github select the file and click on the Raw button)

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: If your question has been answered, then mark it accordingly.